# How do I add more options in a generic Combo Box

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I want to have a combobox like this:

[image]

But in code there is no way of doing it. I'm using MVVM pattern. So I have a view:

```
<ComboBox Style="{StaticResource ComboStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding ResultObjects}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedObject,Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

and ViewModel:

```
public IEnumerable<DateTime> ResultObjects { get;set; }
public DateTime SelectedObject{ get;set; }
```

The fact is that the -All- and -custom- are not DateTime. And it can't be in added to this list.
I remember that in MVC we had a "Dropdown helper".

What can I do here in MVVM?

Comment: You could make that an ObservableCollection<object> and override tostring on an object for your datetimes.

Comment: @Andy It works this time, but in my project I have some other generic lists that I can't handle it by a simple object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could bind to an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<DateTime?, string>>` where the key represent the actual value and the value represents a custom string representation of that value:

```
public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<DateTime?, string>> ResultObjects { get; set; }
public DateTime? SelectedObject { get; set; }

...

ResultObjects = new List<KeyValuePair<DateTime?, string>>()
{
    new KeyValuePair<DateTime?, string>(null, "All"),
    new KeyValuePair<DateTime?, string>(new DateTime(2018,04,17), new DateTime(2018,04,17).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")),
    new KeyValuePair<DateTime?, string>(new DateTime(2018,04,17), new DateTime(2018,04,17).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd @ HH:mm:ss")),
    new KeyValuePair<DateTime?, string>(new DateTime(2018,04,17), "Custom...")
};
...
```

**XAML:**

```
<ComboBox 
    ItemsSource="{Binding ResultObjects}" 
    SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedObject}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Value"
    SelectedValuePath="Key"/>
```

Obviosuly you cannot return anything but actual `DateTime` values from an `IEnumerable<DateTime>` to you should change the type of your source collection if you want to be able to represent other types of values as well.

Comment: I think It's a little bit mad to create key pair for all objects. Isn't there  better solution?

Comment: Thanks for this solution. It works best. I made a select list helper here:
https://gist.github.com/mohsens22/65990e5b3f74d175574a35f24c82d8f1

Answer (score 1):

The way I'd handle this is to define an `ObservableCollection<object>`.
When wpf comes across an object presented to the ui it first looks to see if it's got a template defined for the thing. If it hasn't, it will use ToString on the object.  You can rely on that for simple cases and override .ToString() on any object you want to use.
If you want more sophisticated display than just a string then you can define a datatemplate which targets your objects based on their datatype.
One trick which can be handy.
You can even inherit from one base object and define a template for that, then more specific ones for sub types.  A sub type inheriting from your base object will be dealt with by your "default".

Eg.
I have a map editor.  The user is selecting from different terrains he's going to draw. I want to display different stuff for these. I have a BaseTerrainVM and then I inherit from that for river, contour, woods etc. 
Here's a subset of the markup I use to template the items in a listbox:

```
<ListBox.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:BaseTerrainVM}">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayType}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ContourVM}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayType}" 
                       Grid.Column="0"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        TextElement.FontFamily="Century Gothic"
                        TextElement.FontSize="{DynamicResource LargeFont}"
                        TextElement.FontWeight="Normal"
                        >
                <TextBox MinWidth="50"
                         Text="{Binding Height}"
                         GotKeyboardFocus="TextBox_GotKeyboardFocus"
                         >
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <ui:TextBoxDecimalRangeBehaviour MaxDecimals="0" 
                                         MaxInteger="3" 
                                         Minimum="{StaticResource Zero}" 
                                         Maximum="{StaticResource TwoFiveFive}" />
                        <ui:SelectAllTextBoxBehavior/>
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </TextBox>
                <TextBlock Text="units"
                           Margin="2,0,0,0"
                           ToolTip="Elevation is represented by a number 0-255 which is multiplied by a factor to give metres"
                              />
            </StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" 
                       Grid.Column="2"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:RiverVM}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayType}" 
                       Grid.Column="0"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        TextElement.FontFamily="Century Gothic"
                        TextElement.FontSize="{DynamicResource LargeFont}"
                        TextElement.FontWeight="Normal"
                        >
                <Button 
                        Command="{Binding PressureFromStartCommand}"
                        Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}"
                        Height="20"
                        ToolTip="Widen from Start of stroke"
                        >
                        <Path Data="{StaticResource FlowRight}"
                          Stretch="Uniform"
                          Fill="LightBlue"
                          Stroke="DodgerBlue"
                          StrokeThickness="1"
                          />
                </Button>
                <Button 
                        Command="{Binding PressureConstantCommand}"
                        Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}"
                        Height="20"
                        ToolTip="Constant width for river"
                        >
                    <Rectangle
                          Width="18"
                          Height="6"
                          Fill="LightBlue"
                          Stroke="DodgerBlue"
                          StrokeThickness="1"
                          />
                </Button>
                <Button 
                        Command="{Binding PressureFromEndCommand}"
                        Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}"
                        Height="20"
                        ToolTip="Widen from End of stroke"
                        >
                    <Path Data="{StaticResource FlowRight}"
                          Stretch="Uniform"
                          Fill="LightBlue"
                          Stroke="DodgerBlue"
                          StrokeThickness="1"
                          RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                          >
                        <Path.RenderTransform>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1" ScaleY="1" />
                        </Path.RenderTransform>
                    </Path>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" 
                       Grid.Column="2"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:BoundaryVM}">
        <Grid>
```

( This may amuse Muds. )
My Terrains that presents these is actually a composite collection. In my case this is because I translate all the water on the map into one object so there's no border between one road and the next or a lake and the river flowing into it. I need to present the two representations of water but switch between them.

Comment: I just realised angle brackets in my text meant the observablecollection of object that I wrote displayed as just observablecollection. Fixed the layout.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `CompositeCollection`, that can handle more than one collection/s and other objects.

Try something like this

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="--All--" />
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source=ResultObjects}" />
            <ComboBoxItem Content="--Custom--" />
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Then how can I handle selected item in my View Model?

Comment: 2 ways : either make you resultObject property of type object and check for selected item in view model

other - instead of adding combobox item, add an item of type ResultObject, you can create a new ResultObject item in XAML

select what suits best in your specific case

Comment: just did .. sorry i am not sure which part are you asking for.. just change your ResultObjects to Object and it should work

Comment: I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Good Luck! let us know how did it go

Comment: Not a bad idea for controlling the order.  A composite collection allows you to specify different subtypes for each and it also allows you to implicitly give an order to them. You still need some way to template the different things into UI though.